# Find cell value, match, cut, move, ...vba

Tags: vba

I am a beginner in VBA.
I have components which always consist from 2 parts. (Rotor and a stator, each has its own number). When work is with them it can be damaging some of these parts, however it is necessary to keep a list of damaged parts, where the result is inventory e.g. 200 rotors, stators 150 with different numbers. Before I could scrap it, I need to complete them as proper sets. I.e. rotor "a" stator "a", "b" with "b", etc.  It's crazy to work with many numbers to compare them, copy …to find the result of sets qty.

It is possible to solve it with Macro, what I try to do, but I was stuck. 
What is the task: In the column "A" I have a list of all damaged parts (mix of rotors, stators different numbers). In the column "C" an information only with help of VlookUP, what should be a counterpart number.

What do I need to solve:  In row 5, column. „A“ I have component number , but I know that in the same column, somewhere from row 6 to xx I have a counterpart. What  I need is … according to information from column C, same row(5) where is info about the counterpart num. to find counerpart in column A, when found,  took it out and put into cell B5. Thus,I get a complete set. Then the next row (6), same action. Macro reading num. in „C“,searching in „A“,  when found, cut, and put to „B“ next row 7,8,9,… The result should be a certain qty of pairs + some single numbers if not second part found.

The problem I have is that cycle is working until always found relared counterpart. If the counterpart in row A is not available (no match betwen C-A), the code will stop on that row.

**What I need help with is**, that if code did not find the counerpart based to info from C just skip this row, make it red and continue with next row till end, it means stop on first empty cell in C. Thanks a lot to everybody who is helping me.

```
    Dim pn As Range,
    Dim a
    Dim x
    x = 5
    Dim i As Long, Dim radek As Long
    a = Cells(x, 3)
    For i = 1 To 500
        Range("A:A").Select
        Set pn = Selection.Find(What:=a)
        If Not pn Is Nothing Then 
            pn.Select 
        End If
        Selection.Cut
        Cells(x, 2).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        x = x + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

[image: start]
[image: result]

Comment: Try to make yourself clear with fewer words and try to make them straight to the point. Currently one can get lost trying to understand what you need. Good luck

Comment: My ADD will not let me read this wall of text. Try simplifying the description of your problem. At the very least, break it up into paragraphs or something.

Comment: add data examples

Comment: OK, will try to explain more simply.
Number in column C, row 5 need to find in column A. If found, cut the number, move to B, row 5. If did not find this number , make this number from green to red, skip it and continue with num. in row 6, column C.  Same loop till last cell where number exist in C. Thanks